# How to add HTML attribute without attribute name using TagBuilder?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, tagbuilder

I am building a Input tag using TagBuilder. I want to build the input tag like below

`<input name="IsOkay" type="checkbox" {% if MyObject.IsOkay == true %} checked="checked" {%endif%}  />`

Assume that I already have string `{% if MyObject.IsOkay == true %} checked="checked" {%endif%}` in some variable. *(This is a Liquid template)*

How do I add this string using TagBuilder?

```
   var tag = new TabBuilder("input");
   tag.MergeAttribute("name","IsOkay");
   tag.MergeAttribute("type","checkbox");

   var str = "{% if MyObject.IsOkay == true %} checked="checked" {%endif%}";
   
   how do I add str into tag since there will not be any attribute name?
```

Comment: the model `TagBuilder` uses is well-structured like what of standard html elements. So it's designed to be fairly closed and not for extensibility (you can see that in the source code). You have 3 options: (1) write your own builder which requires a lot of works. (2) when writing using a temp `TextWriter` as a way to get the rendered string, try inserting your `str` into that rendered one (3) if you just use a temp `TextWriter` as a way to get the rendered string, try creating a custom `TextWriter` which overrides `Write` method to detect where you could insert your `str`.

Comment: so for other code that has its own `TextWriter` and consumes your `TagBuilder`, the 2 last options are not usable at all. That means there is only one option to write your own `TagBuilder`, maybe copy all the code from the source code and modify it for your requirement. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/TagBuilder.cs

Comment: The string `{% if MyObject.IsOkay == true %} checked="checked" {%endif%} ` is used to check the checkbox  based on the condition, why not directly according to this condition to merge the `checked` attribute when using TagBuilder? Because, even you add the string in the new tag, it will still according the condition to check the checkbox.

Comment: because when tag builder create html you don't know the actual value of the `MyObject.IsOkay`.  The created html is saved in DB and then dynamic object is passed to the html template. And Liquid then renders html depends on values

Comment: You could try to use the string builder to generate the html string, then use Html. Row () method to render the html in the view.